# Turn off pager for psql's interactive output

Tags: psql

We switched from PostgreSQL 8.3 to 9.0. Perhaps it's a new feature or perhaps just a configuration change, but now when output from commands (like, `\d tablename`) exceeds visible vertical space, psql seem to pipe the output through something similar to `less`. I could not find a way to turn this behaviour off. Any advice? Thanks.

P.S. I'm scrolling the buffer using PuTTY's `Shift+PgUp/PgDn` so I don't need psql's paging. Plus, when I press `q` in the psql's paging, its output disappears from the screen entirely (just like after running `less` in bash), which is wrong from the general use-cases point of view.

Comment: If you're here from Google just trying to scroll through the pager, it's `Space` -- not n or PgDn or down arrow like I tried.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

TL;DR:

`\pset pager 0`

From the \pset section of the [psql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/app-psql.html):

pager

Controls use of a pager program for query and psql help output. If the environment variable PAGER is set, the output is piped to the specified program. Otherwise a platform-dependent default (such as more) is used.

When the pager option is off, the pager program is not used. When the pager option is on, the pager is used when appropriate, i.e., when the output is to a terminal and will not fit on the screen. The pager option can also be set to always, which causes the pager to be used for all terminal output regardless of whether it fits on the screen. \pset pager without a value toggles pager use on and off.

Comment: Thank you. The complete solution looks like: `psql -P pager`.

Comment: I guess you can even put an option in your ~/.psqlrc file to avoid having to enter this every time.

Comment: Anyway to pass arguments to less?

Comment: @snapfractalpop: Please post this as a new question.

Comment: I also ran into Yuri's problem. As described above. You can use `\pset pager` in psql to toggle whether the output goes to the pager. However, you should be able to use a pager and not have the output disappear from the screen when you quit. The answer is to use 'more' instead of 'less' as the pager. You can either do that by setting the PAGER environment variable in your shell or by adding a PAGER environment variable to a ~/.psqlrc file.

Comment: @MichaelRush: Set `PAGER` to `less -X` and it won't clear the screen.

Comment: For others, here's what the -X (or --no-init) option to less does: Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that output that is wider than the current viewport will also trigger the pager, thus leading to confusing behavior such as pagination when there's just a single record. Sorry for resurrecting.

Answer (score 40):

To turn off the pager when using `psql` in the shell :

```
psql -P pager=off ...
```

You could also export an empty `PAGER` environment variable, so you don't need to add the option to every statement. It will stay set until you close your current shell.

```
export PAGER=
psql ...
```

Finally, a workaround that may be easier to remember: pipe the output through `cat`, which will disable the default pager

```
psql ... | cat
```

Comment: Much better answer

Answer (score 26):

Try switcher:

```
database_name=# \pset pager
Pager is used for long output.
database_name=# \pset pager
Pager usage is off.
```

Comment: Also `\pset pager [on|off]` for constant result.

Answer (score 11):

add below code in ~/.psqlrc to retain the behaviour

\pset pager off

Answer (score 10):

Switch the pager off with

```
\pset pager off
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way in summary is to set an environment variable for the pager, e.g.

`PAGER='less -X' psql`

or to set it once

`export PAGER='less -X'`

then run

`psql`

Comment: From the man page: `-X` or `--no-init` - "Disables  sending  the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen."